# django inline foreignkey for multiple model

Tags: django, django-admin

Lets say I have a model :

```
class Info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award, blank=True, null=True)

class Collection(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award, blank=True, null=True)

class Award(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    awarded_date = models.DateField()
```

Here both model `Info` and `Collection` has `ForeignKey` to `Award`.
I want an `Inline` of `Info` and `Collection` with `Award`.

But according to my model structure I can only have `Award` `admin` and `Inline` with it.

I can not register `Award` admin multiple time.

How can I make `Award` `Inline` in admin for models `Info` and `Collection`

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't shared your admin models...

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? You can have multiple inlines.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Info, Collection, Award

class InfoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Info

class CollectionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Collection

@admin.register(Award)
class AwardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (InfoInline, CollectionInline)
```

Comment: I want to register `Info` and `Collection` model seperately with `Award` Inline in both of them..

Comment: Why do you need Inlines then? Inlines are not intended for this. Just use a standard foreign key field. Inlines are for reverse relations.

Comment: With foreign key it gives me dropdown for `Award` but I want to add award in `Info` and `Collection` admin

Comment: You should have a `+` button beside the dropdown to create a new entry. It doesn't make any sens to have inlines this way. Inlines must have a foreign key to the model you are editing.

Comment: I know that there is + button. But I want to display something like what inline ggives me. I want to give input for foreign key instead of selecting from dropdown or clicking + button. I want to add in the same form

Comment: This is out of the scope of django admin.

Comment: Then I think I didn't understand your question.